# Why am I being notified even when nothing is added to the database

Tags: java, firebase-realtime-database, service

I have a child event listener in my service class that is activated whenever the user is online.
The code is like this

```
databaseRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
            shownotification();
            // If any child is added to the database reference
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            // If any child is updated/changed to the database reference
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
          // If any child is removed to the database reference
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
             // If any child is moved to the database reference
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
            Log.e("FirebaseListAdapter", "Listen was cancelled, no more updates will occur");
        }
    });
```

The code works well, the only issue is a notification is shown every time the service class restarts even when a child has not been added, am not sure why this is the case, whether it's because of the child listener or the service class. Kindly assist me. What can be done to solve the problem

Comment: You can put a breakpoint on that method and see what is triggering it.

Comment: On which method? The method for showing the notification or on child added?

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the line where the notification is being triggered. So the line inside of `onChildAdded`. When debugging, your IDE should show a call trace when that line is invoked.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the line where the notification is being triggered. So the line inside of `onChildAdded`. When debugging, your IDE should show a call trace when that line is invoked.

Comment: The trace is dataSnapshot={Datasnapshot@14........}this data was written  sometime back though

Comment: What exactly am I supposed to be looking for and why?

Comment: No, that's a toString of an object. Look at the call stack: the ide will tell you what the sequence of calls is that triggered the call. It will let you see from where exactly the action is originating.